# error 'no '*' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'FloatingPointRoundingRule'

Tags: compiler-errors

Hello after updating to Xcode 8, on the line including '*' I'm getting an error:

'no '*' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'FloatingPointRoundingRule'

```
extension Double {
    mutating func roundToDecimalAgain(_ fractionDigits: Double) -> Double {
        let multiplier = pow(10.0, Double(fractionDigits))
        return round(self * multiplier) / multiplier
   }
}
```

Any ideas?  With thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved:  For swift 3, the rounding rule needed to be written as Darwin.round.

It worked when I changed the line 'return round(self * multiplier) / multiplier' to

return Darwin.round(self * multiplier) / multiplier